# Windows Runtime: Does it include a logging library?

Tags: .net, logging, windows-8, windows-runtime

[`System.Diagnostics.Trace`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.trace.aspx), [`System.Diagnostics.EventLog`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog.aspx), and [`System.Console`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.aspx) all seem to be unavailable. Does WinRT include a logging library?

Comment: Seems pretty implausible that MS removed these from .net. What led you to this conclusion.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I added the correct `using` statements and attempted to access the `EventLog` and `Console` classes, but Visual Studio 11 indicates that they aren't classes of the `System.Diagnostics` and `System` namespaces, respectively. I also thought, "Maybe I'm missing a reference", but the "Add Reference" dialog has nothing in it to add. Whenever I debug the app, I see mscorlib being loaded.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I just tried adding a reference to System by browsing to it, but VS reports "A reference to the component 'System' already exists in the project."

Comment: According to the docs, these classes are present in .net 4.5: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console(v=VS.110).aspx http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.eventlog(v=VS.110).aspx  Is it possible that your installation of the dev previews didn't go right.  What sort of project are you making?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: Hmmm. I am experimenting with the C# Windows Metro style project templates named "Grid Application" and "Split Application". It's not like namespaces `System.Diagnostics` and `System` are not available; they are. It's just that those namespaces do not contain classes `EventLog` and `Console`. Perhaps my dev install was somehow incomplete, like you suggest.

Comment: Would be surprising if metro had console windows

Comment: metro apps are sandboxes and don't have access to the full .net framework.  Many of the exclusions are annoying

Comment: The suggested answer with link to metrolog library is really what you are looking for, since it allows you to persist the log information (to the file) or get it from the device via sharing (almost) out of the box.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only thing I was able to find (System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine()):

```
    //
    // Summary:
    //     Writes a message followed by a line terminator to the trace listeners in
    //     the System.Diagnostics.Debug.Listeners collection.
    //
    // Parameters:
    //   message:
    //     A message to write.
    [Conditional("DEBUG")]
    public static void WriteLine(string message);
```

It writes to the debug output of the Visual Studio's output window.

Comment: So basically, it's good ol' `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine()`?

Answer (score 6):

Check this library out, it's based on NLog:

https://github.com/mbrit/metrolog

Answer (score 2):

Looks like we need a managed wrapper to the c++ EventWrite method.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/aa363752.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can use the System.Diagnostics.Tracing classes in .NET Windows Store Applications (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.tracing.aspx). You cannot write to the Windows Event Log with them, though.

Answer (score 1):

Straight from the horse's mouth: http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Logging-Sample-for-Windows-0b9dffd7

Answer (score 0):

Also, this guys may help you: http://www.moderncomponents.com/products/ConsoleClass/about.php, they're developing a Console Class clone for Windows 8 Metro apps.